# Split a string with slash

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string which includes integers between slashes.
For example:

```
string myString = "/1//2//56//21/";
```

I need to take these integers and add them into a list. How can I split this string to its integers?

Comment: use Split method!  `myString.Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: Too bad the question was closed so soon, because the comment above actually is a better answer than the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string myString = "/1//2//56//21/";
 int[] arrayInt = Regex.Split(myString, "/+").Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: Do you need to escape a `/`? You don't. `split("XXX", "/")` is enough. Correct me if I'm wrong.